# Need to hide and show header of top tab navigation in react native. Works on first tab, but fails on another tab

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, interpolation

I Want to hide and show header of application on scroll, but it works on first tab, but fails on another tab.

Following is my header and tab bar code

```
<Animated.View style={{height: headerHeight}}>
  <Header centerComponent={{
     text: 'Success Steps',
    }}
  />
</Animated.View>

<Tab.Navigator
 tabBarOptions={{
 style: {backgroundColor: red},
}}>
<Tab.Screen
 name="screen1"/>
<Tab.Screen
 name="screen2"/>
/>
```

following is my interpolation code.

```
scrollY.interpolate({
 inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
 outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
 extrapolate: 'clamp',
}),
```

I have called Animated.event method on scroll from child component, following is screen1 code

```
render() {
    return (
      <Animated.ScrollView
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.scrollY}}}],
          {
            useNativeDriver: true,
          },
        )}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Screen 1</Text>
        </View>
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    );
```

I have passed scrollY from screen1 and screen2 to parent component(Header component),

Comment: can u add code  navigator page and the 2 tabs page

Comment: I have added tab1 code, but navigation code, I have already added. i.e. <Tab.Navigator>

Comment: do u need same header in both tabs or 2 seperate headers for each

Comment: same header, i.e success Steps. in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used Animated.add() on landing screen

```
this.state = {
      tab1ScrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
      tab2ScrollY: new Animated.Value(0),
    };

const scrollY = new Animated.add(
      this.state.tab1ScrollY,
      this.state.tab2ScrollY,
    );
```

and passed that to tab components

```
<TopTabNavigator
     tab1ScrollY={this.state.tab1ScrollY}
     tab2ScrollY={this.state.tab2ScrollY}
/>
```

And following is my tab1 code

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollY: this.props.tab1ScrollY,
    };
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <Animated.ScrollView
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}],
          {
            useNativeDriver: true,
          },
        )}>
        <View><Text>Tab_1<Text></View>
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

This helped me to solve my problem

Comment: This solves my problem except one thing, after scrolling on Tab1 when you navigate to Tab2 you can't scroll down so the header gets stuck, unless you move back to Tab1 and scroll. @Ashwith Saldanha, do you know, what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use context to pass scroll value to the screen and onScroll change the value

snack: https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/paranoid-ice-cream

code:

```
const TabContext = React.createContext();

function HomeScreen() {
  const { y } = React.useContext(TabContext);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 50 }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onScroll={onScrollEvent({ y })}>
        <View style={[styles.viwe, { backgroundColor: 'green' }]} />
        <View style={[styles.viwe, { backgroundColor: 'blue' }]} />
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  const { y } = React.useContext(TabContext);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      }}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: 50 }}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onScroll={onScrollEvent({ y })}>
        <View style={[styles.viwe, { backgroundColor: 'green' }]} />
        <View style={[styles.viwe, { backgroundColor: 'blue' }]} />
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const y = useValue(0);

  const translateY = interpolate(y, {
    inputRange: [0, 50],
    outputRange: [0, -50],
    extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });

  return (
    <TabContext.Provider value={{ y }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.header, { transform: [{ translateY }] }]} />
    </TabContext.Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viwe: {
    width: 300,
    height: 500,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  header: {
    height: 50,
    zIndex: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: I am getting this.props.onScroll is not function, after implementing this